# Adobe AcroTray in Startup

Tags: boot

I want to minimize the items that start-up in the Task Manager.  Do I need Adobe AcroTray to run in startup?

Comment: You only need it if you want the features it offers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a personal preference, if you would like to take full advantage of your start up items, please go to start> type 'msconfig' select it. Go to Start up items, and de select any you do not need.